# Using React.net with ASP.NET Core with Webpack to render individual components server-side

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core, webpack

Please excuse my ignorance. I am coming from a non .net background and attempting to get up to speed but I have been having trouble finding good documentation on integrating react with ASP.NET Core MVC.

I am looking to utilize react.Net in order to implement server side rendering of react components...

The site for react.net has some example code on GitHub,
https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/tree/master/tutorial-code

but the tutorial falls short of explaining how to utilize web pack. This solution is fairly useless to me as I need to be able to initially render react components for both speed and for being able to use data passed by the controller to the view without using a third party library to fetch data.

I was wondering if anyone had good insights or examples of how to utilize react.net in a way that allows for
1. reuse of react components using imports
2. allows passing data from the controller to the view to the component as a prop.

Thanks.

Comment: I wrote an article in late 2017 - it is not up to date - but it may get you started.
https://codeburst.io/how-to-use-webpack-in-asp-net-core-projects-a-basic-react-template-sample-25a3681a5fc2

Comment: Thanks for the response I have read your article already. it was fantastic. Im most likely going to utilize a client side rendering architecture if I cannot implement serverside.
Perhaps you could help with a question about webpack. Based off of your tutorial, how would I go about adding an additional view, and only load react components that I want in that view?
My worry is that I currently have an app.js marked as the entry point but if I add an additional view I would like to add an additional entry point for it. I've been looking online and nothing is fitting exactly as I would like.